# How to automatically insert multiple photos into a PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Is there a way to "interrupt" a PowerPoint presentation and display a photo from a local folder and then go on with the presentation? Is it possible to show a random photo after every 5th slide?

The PowerPoint presentation is already finished, and there is a folder on the prensentation computer which contains the photos.

Comment: (as it's not a native fonction, I don't understand the close vote).

Comment: I suppose a VBA macro can do the job...